# How can I fake constructor inheritance in C++03?

Tags: c++, constructor, code-reuse, c++03

As far as I know, you cannot inherit constructors in C++. But there are situations, where it might be required that it looks like you can instantiate inherited classes the same way you instantiate their base:

```
struct Base {
  int i;
  int const j;
  Base(int i, int j) : i(i), j(j) {}
};

// option 1)
struct Derived1 : Base {
  Derived1(int i, int j) : Base(i,j) {}
};
Base* baseFactory() {
  return new Derived1(42,47);
}

// option 2)
struct Derived2 : Base {
};
Base* baseFactory() {
  Base* b = new Derived2();
  b->i = 42;
  b->j = 47; // broken!
  // alternative could be to implement Base::operator=
  return b;
}
```

Note that the derived classes could be default constructed if it weren't for their base class(es).

Option 1 is what is usually done, I think, but you are typing code without expressing anything new. Option 2 breaks `const` correctness (and prevents you from using references as members) because everything must be assignable.

Is there a nice way around this?

**Edit**: C++11 is great, but unfortunately I need a C++03 solution.

Comment: If you can, use c++11, solves your problem directly.

Comment: I don't understand what you find wrong with your first option... It's the standard way of initializing the base object during construction. If you later need more initializations done you can update the fields accordingly in the derived callses C'tor body.

Comment: Option 2 does not compile at all, so how can it be an option?

Comment: @UncleBens: I works if you have no `const` or `&` members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative approach:

```
// option 3)
struct Derived3 : Base {
  Derived3(const Base &b) : Base(b) {}
};
Base* baseFactory3() {
    return new Derived3(Base(42,47));
}
```

This may not be a good idea if constructing a full Base object is expensive or requires external resources.  In that case you could create a light-weight object that carries constructor arguments for Base, so that instead of multiple Base constructors you have multiple BaseArguments constructors, and one Base constructor that takes in BaseArguments.  However I don't think many people would consider that good style in most circumstances.

Comment: -1 That's such a bad solution. Leaving aside that you should use dependency injection instead, this is just convoluted and it's hard to understand what's happening.

Comment: @Paul Manta: I'm very inclined to accept this answer, as it strikes me as the cleanest solution. However, you seem to have strong critique, so perhaps you would care to elaborate or post a better answer yourself?

Comment: @bitmask: Paul seems to just be saying that it's confusing.  Also, if Base can be given a C++03 move constructor `Base(Base& rhs, int moveconstructor)` then you don't have to worry about the weight of `Base`, which increases speed (sometimes) and confusion.

Comment: @Mooing Regarding C++03 move constructors, this article by Alexandrescu is interesting: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403855

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 is the idiomatic way in C++03, it does require more typing, but that is how the language is. Option 2 is not even close to equivalent, you would not be able to initialize `Derived2` as `Base` does not have a default constructor, and the definition of the *implicitly declared* default constructor for `Derived2` needs it.

But beyond the technical difficulty in the language you are trading *construction* for *two-phase construction* which is never a good idea, and at the same time forcing your use of `Derived2` to dynamically allocated objects.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 supports inherited constructors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11

However not all compilers that supports now a subset of C++11 supports all functionalities.

Microsoft visual C++ 2010 supports several new C++0x features but not inherited constructors, here is a list: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx

GCC supports more new features but not the inherited constructors. See http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

To enable GCC to compile with C++0x features you need to add `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` compilation parameter.
Visual C++ 2010 have these enabled by default.

You just need to wait :)

There are not clean solutions for previous version of the standard, for this reason it was introduced in C++11, because it was not possible to do with previous versions.
So, the only thing you can do, is to copy your constructors and call base constructor.

Comment: To the topic of waiting: I'm like a Star Trek starship captain: I want everything and I want it now (and on all platforms) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here' a variation on the Builder Pattern that I always thought it could be useful, but I never actually got a chance to use it; I guess you could call it the Constructor Pattern. :P

It also offers some other advantages, like not having to specify arguments in a certain order: you only specify what you are interested in and in whatever order you want.

I still think this is justified only if your class has lots of constructors with different parameters. Otherwise, it's just an annoyance.

```
class Person
{
  public:
    class Constructor;
};

class Person::Constructor
{
  public:
    Constructor& name(const std::string&);
    Constructor& age(int);
    Person* make();
};

Person* pers = Person::Constructor()
    .name("Bob Marley").make();


class Employee : public Person
{
  public:
    class Constructor;
};

class Employee::Constructor : public Person::Constructor
{
  public:
    Constructor& salary(double);
    Employee* make();
};

Employee* emp = Employee::Constructor()
    .name("Emilly Smith").age(23).make();
```

But again, this is justifiable only if your class has lots of constructors with lots of parameters and you want to avoid having to write multiple overloads to those; otherwise, this just adds too much complexity without any real benefit.

I mentioned I don't like han's proposed solution. This is because (1) you are moving the need to (re)declare a number of constructors in the child class to the need to place the same number of functions inside a factory class; (2) it is hacky and the intent is not explicit; and (3) you could view this as a violation of dependency injection.

Comment: When I've seen this in the past, the constructor was the parameter to a `Person` constructor, which allowed local allocation.  I also don't immediately see how this addresses the OP's question.

Comment: @Mooing: I think the idea is that the parents constructor arguments are inherited by the child constructors, by way of the `Employee::Constructor` inheriting from `Person::Constructor`.

Comment: This is handy if the problem is multiple (or complex) constructors, but not if it's just copying a small number of constructors to derived classes.

Comment: If you make your `Person::Constructor` a base class of `Person`, you save a lot of member-name typing. Now, change the `Constructor::make()` method into a constructor of Person `Person(Constructor&)` to allow easier object construction. But hey, that's basically what han was proposing.

Comment: @bitmask You save name typing but it doesn't make sense to do that.