# Delay true base class construction with placement new

Tags: c++, placement-new, construction

I'm asking if (and why) the following approach is a) legal and b) moral. I'm asking with emphasis on C++03, but notes on C++11 are welcome, too. The idea is to prevent derived classes that could themselves be default constructible from implementing stupid `B::B(int foo) : A(foo) {}` constructors.

```
class Base {
  private:
    int i;
    Base(int i) : i(i) {}
  protected:
    Base() {}
  public:
    static Base* create(int i);
};
class Derived : public Base {
};

Base* Base::create(int i) {
  Derived* d = new Derived();
  Base* b = static_cast<Base*>(d);
  delete b;
  new(b) Base(i);
  return d;
}
```

My gut is telling me, that something is fishy here. If any `Derived` class accesses `Base` members in its constructor, I want to be somewhere else, but otherwise I have trouble seeing valid reasons why the approach is bad.

Anyway, if you think this is an acceptable approach, how would to deal with reference members (something like `int& Base::j`)?

*Note:* This is a follow-up question to [How can I fake constructor inheritance in C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938204/how-can-i-fake-constructor-inheritance-in-c03).

---

**Edit**: I must have been distracted when posting the question. Of course, instead of `delete b` I meant `b->~Base()`. I blame low blood sugar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is incorrect and triggers undefined behavior. Your `Base` class does not have a virtual destructor, which means that the `delete b` will cause Undefined Behavior.

The reasons for UB in the call to `delete` range from the fact that it will not *release* the derived resources (which seems to be the purpose of the code, ouch!), to the fact that it will try to release the allocated memory, which might work or not, depending on the layout of both objects. If it fails to deallocate the memory it will probably crash, if it succeeds the placement new call in the following line will try to initialize an object in memory that has already been released...

Even if you changed the code (trying to avoid deallocation problems) to:

```
Base* Base::create(int i) {
   Derived *d = new Derived;
   Base * b = static_cast<Base*>(d);
   b->~Base();                       // destruct, do not deallocate
   new (b) Base(i);
   return d;
}
```

Where there is no `delete` and thus *that particular* source of Undefined Behavior is gone, the code is still undefined behavior (probably in too many ways to even mention). For once the call to the destructor is still UB, even if that was not, the fact that you recreated the `Base` type means that dynamic dispatch for that object will probably consider the object to be a `Base` rather than a `Derived` object (in the case of `vtable`s, the `vptr` that points to the RunTime Type information will refer to `Base`, rather than `Derived`)

And there are probably two or three other things that can go wrong and I cannot think of right now...

Comment: If it had one, I'd be calling `~Derived`, when I say `delete b`, wouldn't I. That's not what I want.

Comment: @bitmask: It doesn't matter what you want... the language does not allow you to call delete on a pointer to a base class unless the base class has a virtual destructor.

Comment: @bitmask: There are too many things wrong in the approach to discuss all of them, but you would have to think, for example, on memory allocation/deallocation, runtime type of the objects at each point in time...

Comment: By now, I'm absolutely convinced that it is evil. As I said, before, I had a hunch, but nothing more. Thanks for confirming that hunch.

Answer (score 1):

`delete b` does not just call `Base`s destructor, it also deallocates the memory returned by `new` and calls `Derived`s destructor [assuming you intended `Base` to have a virtual destructor... if you intended it to be non-virtual, the behavior is simply undefined to begin with].  Which means your subsequent use of placement new is constructing a whole new `Base` object in memory that is no longer valid, and you are never replacing the portion of `Derived` that you destroyed earlier.  In short, nothing you have done even approaches correct behavior.

Frankly, I don't see what you're trying to do... why must `Derived` be default constructed, instead of just forwarding an argument?  Its not stupid, its the way things are done.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. Sometimes I try to make something better and end up making it worse by orders of magnitude. It's a recurring pattern.